# What is the best App Analytics available for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, analytics

I know there are lot of Application Analytics platform available like, Google Analytics, Flurry, etc..

But I am not sure which is the best one. Heard of some issues with Analytics like missing events , issues in getting crash events.

Can you please share your suggestions regarding the best App Analytics? This is like a open discussion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Crashlytics.

Crashlytics is a free service offered by Twitter that collects your crashes and various other bits of information. Its very easy to setup and install and it instantly starts providing value as soon as you install it – yes, even in development. Its completely free, unlimited apps, unlimited users, unlimited crashes, unlimited keys, etc – its all free. I’m not joking when I say its the first thing I install. Without crash reporting I have no idea whats happening to my app in the wild (production).

Read More about Crashlytics https://try.crashlytics.com/